# local variable named 'myList' cannot be declared in this scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting

Can anyone explain to me to know what this error is and why I got it? 
I have tried to change the name `f` the variable but it didn't work.

```
public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, string CurrentFilter, string SearchString, int? page)
{

    ViewBag.CurrentSort = SortOrder;
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SortOrder) ? "Tillverkning desc" : "";
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = SortOrder == "HireDate" ? "HireDatedesc" : "HireDate";

    conn.Open();

    ProductionOrderList myList = new  ProductionOrderList();
    myList = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrders(conn, new Guid("288937bcc-6uif-485a-anm9-fadfq1234039d"));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {     
        // here on myList get red line     
        myList = myList.Where( myList => myList .ProductionOrderNo.ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because C# supports [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). The compiler is complaining because the lambda parameter `myList` must have a different name than any variables in the outer scope.

Try this:

```
myList = myList.Where(x => x.ProductionOrderNo.ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper()));
```

See [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

---

The next issue you have is that `myList` is of type `ProductionOrderList` while `Where` retuns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Unless you *need* to use a custom collection type, I wouldn't use it. Try this:

```
 IEnumerable<tionOrderItem> myList = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrders(...);
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
 {     
      // here on myList get red line     
      myList = myList.Where(x => x .ProductionOrderNo.ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper()));
 }

 ...
```

Or, you really *must* use an instance of `ProductionOrderList`, make sure you have a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, and use this:

```
 ProductionOrderList myList = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrders(...);
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
 {     
      // here on myList get red line     
      myList = new ProductionOrderList(
          myList.Where(x => x .ProductionOrderNo.ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper())));
 }
```

Comment: Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SystemCompany.Database.Production.ProductionOrderItem>' to 'SystemCompany.Database.Production.ProductionOrderList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)


my productionOrderItem is an item in ProductionOrderList

Comment: @FadiAlkadi I've added more info on that error. See my updated error.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
myList = myList.Where( item => item .ProductionOrderNo.ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SystemCompany.Database.Production.ProductionOrderItem>' to 'SystemCompany.Database.Production.ProductionOrderList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)


my productionOrderItem is an item in ProductionOrderList